# Using older React version 15.4 - Using CreateRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an older version of React and the version is 15.4. This version doesn't support createRef()

I've code which works for React 16.8 or later but doesn't work for this version. getting an error which is

> c.default.createRef is not a function

Here's my code whihc works for React 16.8 or later version

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    const TrustBox = ({ trustBoxRef }) => (
      <div ref={trustBoxRef} className="trustpilot-widget">
        <a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/review/example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        Trustpilot
        </a>
      </div>
    );
    class TrustBoxContainer extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.trustBoxRef = React.createRef();
      }
      
    componentDidMount() {
            if (window.Trustpilot) {
            window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(this.trustBoxRef.current, true);
            }
    }
      
    render() {
            return <TrustBox trustBoxRef={this.trustBoxRef} />;
      }
    
    }
    export default TrustBoxContainer;
```

I did a lot of research on how to get the older version to work but in vain. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Check the [old docs](https://react-legacy.netlify.app/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Thank you @BrianThompson, the docs helped a bit.